# Bluebird warning "A promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it"

Tags: node.js, express, bluebird

I get the warning about not returning a created promise from Bluebird and I do not understand why and how I should rewrite my code.

(I have tried reading about the warning at [Bluebird API](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/docs/docs/warning-explanations.md#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it) page and the [anti-pattern page](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) as I suspect this is what I'm doing)

In my view.js file:

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    settings = myReq('config/settings'),
    Sets = myReq('lib/Sets'),
    log = myReq('lib/utils').getLogger('View');

router.get('/:setId/', function(req, res, next) {
    var
        setId = req.params.setId,  
        user = req.user,
        set = new Sets(setId, user);

    log.info('Got a request for set: ' + setId);

    // The below line gives the warning mentioned
    set.getSet().then(function(output) {
        res.send(output);

    }).error(function(e){
        log.error(e.message, e.data);
        res.send('An error occurred while handling set:' + e.message);
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

In my Sets.js file I have:

```
var
    Promise = require('bluebird'),
    OE = Promise.OperationalError,
    settings = myReq('config/settings'),
    UserData = myReq('lib/userData'),
    log = myReq('lib/utils').getLogger('sets'),
    errorToSend = false;

module.exports = function(setId, user) {
    var 
        sets = myReq('lib/utils').getDb('sets');

    return {

        getSet : function() {

            log.debug('Getting set')

            return sets.findOneAsync({
                setId:setId
            }).then(function(set){
                if ( set ) {
                    log.debug('got set from DB');
                } else {
                    set = getStaticSet(setId);
                    if ( ! set ) {
                        throw new OE('Failed getting db records or static template for set: ' + setId );
                    }
                    log.debug('got static set');
                }

                log.debug('I am handling set')

                if ( ! checkSet(set) ) {
                    var e = new OE('Failed checking set');
                    e.data = set;
                    throw e;
                }

                return {
                    view : getView(set),
                    logic : set.logic,
                    canEdit : true,
                    error : errorToSend
                };

            });
        }
    };
};
```

So the line in my view.js file with "set.getSet()" gives the warning about not returning the created promise. It seems like this script still does what I expect it to do, but I do not understand why I get the warning.

Stacktrace:

```
Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
    at Object.getSet (C:\dev\infoscrn\lib\Sets.js:36:25)
    at C:\dev\infoscrn\routes\view.js:39:20
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at next (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:110:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:91:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:267:22
    at param (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:340:14)
    at param (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:356:14)
    at Function.proto.process_params (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:400:3)
    at next (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
    at Function.proto.handle (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:166:3)
    at router (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:35:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:302:13)
    at C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:270:7
    at Function.proto.process_params (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:321:12)
    at next (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:261:10)
    at C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:603:15
    at next (C:\dev\infoscrn\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:246:14)
```

Comment: It's probably in the `set.getSet` function. Just share your stack trace as it will help with identifying the exact location of the issue.

Comment: Here's the stack trace:

Comment: I have tried to update all deps but the warning is still there. I would really like to keep getting these type of warnings as I find them usefull, so I do not want to turn them off globaly. But this one I do not understand.... :-)

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Comment: @RémiBecheras Nope, not yet...

Comment: I've managed to avoid this warning by using 

.then(() => next(), e => next(e));
instead of

.then(() => next())
.catch(e => next(e));

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First, try and [update all your dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates). There's been a recent version of Bluebird, which fixed [an issue involving this warning](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/846).

Next, make sure you [return from all your handlers](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-none-were-returned-from-it).

Then, if you still get the warning (like I do) you can [disable this specific warning](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.config.html). I chose to do so by setting `BLUEBIRD_W_FORGOTTEN_RETURN=0` in my environment.

Comment: There is something broken with babel6 await async, therefore I confirm that it must be disabled on Node.js

Comment: How do you disable that?

Answer (score 13):

Don't disable warnings. They're there for a reason.

The typical pattern is that if your onfulfill or onreject handler causes a Promise to be constructed, it will return that Promise (or some chain derived from it) from the handler, so that the chain adopts the state of that Promise.

So Bluebird is keeping track of when it is running one of your handler functions, and also keeping track of when it's Promise constructor is called. If it determines that a Promise was created at *any point* while your handler is running (that includes anywhere down in the callstack), but that Promise was *not* returned from your handler, it issues this warning because it thinks you probably *forgot* to write the return statement.

So if you legitimately don't care about the Promise that was created inside the handler, all you have to do is explicitly return something from your handler. If you don't care about what is returned from your handler (i.e., if you don't care what value the Promise fulfills with), then simply return `null`. Whatever you return, the explicit return (specifically, a return value other than `undefined`) tells Bluebird that you think you know what you're doing, and it won't issue this warning.

Comment: While I agree generally with the statement "Don't disable warnings. They're there for a reason," for this specific warning I don't think it applies.  This warning comes up because bluebird wants to see a `return null;` statement in certain situations - but if you do a `resolve();` and have no further code, then adding a `return null;` is useless noise in the code.

Comment: @kris I'm not really clear what the `resolve()` is, in this case. I agree that adding `return null` can be a little extra noise is the code, and is somewhat likely to confuse someone who doesn't know why it's there. What we settled on for our team was to define a const equal to `null` named `NO_PROMISE_RETURNED`, and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that every place you have `return` statement which is the solution works for me.