# React Js ALT - Call function on Success of another

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, alt

In the Alt Actions code below, how can I call getCharacters() after success of addCharacter? Basically I am trying to refresh list of characters after saving a new record to database.

```
getCharacters() {
    requestPromise('http://localhost:3100/api/characters')
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Getting Characters");
        var opdata = JSON.parse(res);
        this.actions.getCharactersSuccess(opdata.characters);
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('error:', err);
        this.actions.getCharactersFail(err)
      })
  }

  addCharacter(data) {
    var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'http://localhost:3100/api/characters/add/',
      json: true,
      body: {
        name: data.charName,
        allegiance: data.charAllegiance,
      },
    };
    requestPromise(options)
      .then((res) => {
          // How can I recall getCharacters() from here
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('error:', err);
      })
  }
```

**STORE**

```
getCharactersSuccess(res) {
    this.setState({
      characters: res
    })
  }
```

Comment: check this one, might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370957/bluebird-warning-a-promise-was-created-in-a-handler-but-was-not-returned-from-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look right.It would be better if are you using any architecture like flux or redux. Any way you can do it buy just calling`return this.getCharacters();`. Which refers to the getCharacters() function inside your class. the key point you missed is **return this.** which select the correct reference And the error occurs when you create a promise inside a promise scope, but you don't return anything from that Promise scope. So **return** will fix your issue.

```
addCharacter(data) {
    var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'http://localhost:3100/api/characters/add/',
      json: true,
      body: {
        name: data.charName,
        allegiance: data.charAllegiance,
      },
    };
    requestPromise(options)
      .then((res) => {
         return this.getCharacters();
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('error:', err);
      })
  }
```

Comment: I am using AltJs. I have tried this solution but receive error : a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Comment: Try adding a return keyword in front of this.getCharacters();

Comment: hmm, this get rid of the warning, however the response of getCharacters being returned as undefined.

Comment: hmm this might be caused by the asycn nature of js try something like 
this.getCharacters();
return "";

Comment: no luck still the same error, it's strange because I am console logging opData and it is returning as expected un until the getCharactersSuccess()

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the getCharacters function.  You can do that by `this.getCharacters()`

```
addCharacter(data) {
    var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'http://localhost:3100/api/characters/add/',
      json: true,
      body: {
        name: data.charName,
        allegiance: data.charAllegiance,
      },
    };
    requestPromise(options)
      .then((res) => {
         return this.getCharacters();
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('error:', err);
      })
  }
```

Comment: I tried this but receive error: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it

Comment: you receive a warning, not an error. you just need to add `return this.getCharacters()`